# Adding a CTE for month and Year with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to add a date column with CTE instead of creating a calendar table?

I need the outcome to be something like:

```
Month/Year
01/2018
02/2018
'
'
'
12/2020
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  But a better way uses `generate_series()`:

```
select *
from generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2020-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(yyyymm)
```